# how to remove blankspace from output java

Tags: java

heloo new here and still learning, im trying to study code from https://www.javatpoint.com/program-to-find-the-duplicate-characters-in-a-string
, but i have obstacle on it.

i want to select non-duplicate number on string i could, i got print 4

my input 1 2 3 4 3 2 1

but output is

```
Duplicate characters 
 
 
 
4
```

```
public class DuplicateCharacters {  
     public static void main(String[] args) {  
        String string1 = "1 2 3 4 3 2 1";  
        int count;  
          
        
        char string[] = string1.toCharArray();  
          
        System.out.println("Non-Duplicate characters ");  
        
        for(int i = 0; i <string.length; i++) {  
            count = 1;  
            for(int j = i+1; j <string.length; j++) {  
                if(string[i] == string[j] && string[i] != ' ') {  
                    count++;  
                    string[j] = '0';  
                }  
            }  
           
            if(count == 1 && string[i] != '0')  
                System.out.println(string[i]);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

expected output

```
Duplicate characters 
4
```

i try to put println out from loop but it get error, sorry for my bad grammar

Comment: I don't get that output out of that code. If you don't want the spaces to be printed, make your input String "1234321" instead of "1 2 3 4 3 2 1"

Comment: okay, remove space in input it work, if i change it to a word like String string1 = "a bag"; the blank space is still there

Comment: i go String string1 = "a bag", it had blank space, but String string1 = "abag" no space, how it work?

Comment: example  String string1 = "a bag in a basket";   Non-Duplicate characters 
 
g
 
i
n
 
 
s
k
e
t it random has blank space on it

Comment: im running in https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/

Comment: You are printing a blank line for each space in the input string.  Read your code carefully.

Comment: spaces are NOT being counted/eliminated (`!= ' '`) but printed (`count == 1 && ... != '0'`)

Comment: okay addding !=' ' it work for number and alfabet

Comment: but how to make true definition like result = (count == 1 && string[i] != '0' && string[i] != ' ')  
                System.out.println(result);  , ?? so i can move println from looping

Answer (score 1):

Your problem are the blanks in your input. If you don´t want to count those you should simply sanitize your input.

```
int count;
string1 = string1.replaceAll(" ", "");

char string[] = string1.toCharArray();
```

I am however a little bit confused what you want achive. Your code returns all non duplicate characters. If you want to get all the duplicate characters you could have a look at my approach for this:

```
    String input = "1 2 3 4 3 2 1";
    List<Character> countedCharactersAsMoreThanOne = new ArrayList<>();
    input = input.replaceAll(" ","");
    input = input + " ";

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
        Character currentCharacter = input.charAt(i);
        String[] split = input.split(Character.toString(currentCharacter));
        if(split.length > 2 && 
           !countedCharactersAsMoreThanOne.contains(currentCharacter)){
            countedCharactersAsMoreThanOne.add(currentCharacter);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Number of duplicate characters:");
    System.out.println(countedCharactersAsMoreThanOne.size());
    System.out.println("All duplicated characters");
    System.out.println(countedCharactersAsMoreThanOne);
```